# Is safe to hide piece of paper with bios password on it inside notebook?

Tags: bios, passwords, bootloader, password-protection

If someone stole my notebook they try to reinstall system and delete all of my work. I want to lock bootloader with password but i'm afraid of forgetting it myself. I like to know if is safe to hide piece of paper inside notebook and duck-tape it to case(removable piece, there is RAM under it).I know about massive amount of heat inside computers and i'm afraid that paper get ignited and burn my computer. So, it is safe ?

---

EDIT :
So if it is bad idea, where i should hide password ?
PS. I'm BedRoom coder specialized in gamedev, of course i'm worried about my work, it taking 4 years already.

Comment: I have a few key passwords written on the back of something hanging on my wall.  The trick is, even if someone found where I have these written they wouldn’t understand how to use the information that they found, it makes perfect sense to me—but was created in a manner to specifically confuse anyone else.

Comment: Make the password something like you've not to memorize like birthday, first school date etc.

Answer (score 1):

If I stole your laptop, and I would find that it is password protected, I would open up the laptop to try and clear the battery.

I would therefor find your note, and by that reasoning, it is not a good idea to hide the note there.

That said, temperatures inside a laptop should not exceed critical temperatures for paper to catch fire. You may want to consider changing the password to something you can remember, and just put that 5 times in a row.

For example, if the password you can remember is: `good`, consider to make it `goodgoodgoodgood` It is better than to just hide the password.

Alternatively, if its a password you won't be using much, consider to turn the laptop upside down and check for a sticker that has any text on it, for example the serial number. Write that down on a paper, turn the laptop back up, and use that as password. The password is physically on the laptop, but no one will guess that you used that.

EDIT: Based on your latest edit, you should not worry about that password, but on how to protect your files from being stolen. Even if they steal your laptop and cannot access the files, you can't access them anymore either. Consider using an external harddisk to place your files on, and leave the harddisk at home. This will limit your development to when you are at home, but the harddisk can be hidden.

Using Bitlocker, you can protect it with a password, but bitlocker also has the option to save its encryption to a file. If you buy a cheap usb drive, you can use that as a key for your harddisk. You can even make the laptop require this usb stick to use the laptop.

You then attach that usb stick to your key chain and you have a much better protection.

Answer (score 0):

"*Is it safe?*" (i.e: will it burst into flames?) - no, it shouldn't

"*Is it safe?*" (i.e: is it a safe (sensible) place to store a BIOS password?) - no

---

If your threat model indicates that someone might try to reinstall the OS, then storing the password that is preventing this from occuring ***in** or **on*** the physical machine itself is a ***bad idea***.

I'm suprised that you're more worried about someone reinstalling / deleting your work, rather than stealing work and/or access, passwords, etc...

---

Note also that placing paper inside a laptop can block ventillation, causing thermal issues...

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing inside a laptop that should get hot enough to ignite paper, if it does, you have far greater issues.

However, if someone steals your laptop and opens it up after not getting past POST, then you have defeated the object.

Safe, yes.
Good idea, no.

Answer (score 0):

It won't catch fire, but it's still a bad idea.   Any time you attach the physical copy of a password to the object it protects, you effectively render the password meaningless.   Not only that, but you're protecting the wrong thing.

If someone steals your notebook, you hope and pray all they are doing is reinstalling an OS and deleting all of your work.  That also gets rid of all of your personal information, and your work should be backed up using a cloud service (OneDrive, Dropbox, Google Drive) or onto optical disks that have a long shelf life (BD-ROM) or other media.  Its your operating system and account passwords you should be worried about, because if someone steals your notebook, *you're not going to get it back, no matter how much the person who sold you a protection plan said otherwise.*  It will either never be found, or will be kept in an evidence locker.  Insurance just replaces the lost machine.

Answer (score 0):

Storing credentials for something directly inside or outside of that something is never a good idea. Even if you give only a hint on that note and not the real thing, that gives an attacker a valid vector for his attack.

The smarter solution to your problem would be to use a password safe and store the necessary credentials there. Another great plus for the use of such a tool is that you can generate strong passwords because you do not have to remember them.